# How to pass multiple variables across multiple pages?

Tags: php, html, form-submit

My website involves a user submitting data over several pages of forms. I can pass data submitted on one page straight to the next page, but how do I go about sending it to pages after that? Here's a very simplified version of what I'm doing.

Page 1:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='page2.php' method='post'>
Please enter your name: <input type='text' name='Name'/>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/></form>";
?>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["Name"];
echo "Hello $name!<br/>
<form action='page3.php' method='post'>
Please enter your request: <input type='text' name='Req'/>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/></form>";
?>
```

Page 3:

```
<?php
echo "Thank you for your request, $name!";
?>
```

The final page is supposed to display the user's name, but obviously it won't work because I haven't passed that variable to the page. I can't have all data submitted on the same page for complicated reasons so I need to have everything split up. So how can I get this variable and others to carry over?

Comment: Besides of the technical feasibilities, this brings several usability problems. I'd recommend making it all in 1 form, instead of several and many clicks.

Answer (score 7):

Use sessions:

`session_start();` on every page

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

then on page3 you can echo `$_SESSION['name']`

Comment: Isn't that session_start()?

Comment: @JasonStack: Yes it is! Wow, 4 years later!

Answer (score 1):

You could store the data in a *cookie* on the user's client, which is abstracted into the concept of a *session*. See [PHP session management](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want cookies or sessions: 
use a hidden input field in second page and initialize the variable by posting it like:

```
page2----

$name=$_POST['name'];  /// from page one

<form method="post" action="page3.php">
 <input type="text" name="req">
 <input type="hidden" name="holdname" value="<? echo "$name"?>"> 
 ////////you can start by making the field visible and see if it holds the value
</form>

page3----

$name=$_POST['holdname'];    ////post the form in page 2
$req=$_POST['req'];    ///// and the other field
echo "$name, Your name was successfully passed through 3 pages";
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, saving the data in SESSION is probably your best bet.

Alternatly you could add the data to a hidden field, to post it along:

page2:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $name;?>"/>
```

page3

```
echo "hello $_POST['username'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create sessions, and use posts. You could also use $_GET to get variables from the URL.

Remember, if you aren't using prepared statements, make sure you escape all user input...

Answer (score 0):

Use SESSION variable or hidden input field

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround of this problem: instead of manually typing in hidden input fields, I just go foreach over $_POST:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $value . '" />';
}
```

Hope this helps those with lots of fields in $_POST :)